# Am I unable to call a method with this style of User Input?

Tags: c#, methods, user-input

I am trying to call a method with the inputs stated within Main. I have seen that some people get user inputs from another method besides Main but wanted to complete it this way. Is it possible?

I am able to input data when asked as stated. Although, "Your answer is: " returns nothing.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number1, number2;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter another number: ");
            number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is: ", Add(number1, number2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int Add(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting break points and stepping through your code, observing what the actual values of your variables are at each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't have any string format tokens in your text `Your answer is:`.  Try adding `{0}` like this: `Your answer is: {0}` or maybe even `{0} is your answer.`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0#system-console-writeline(system-string-system-object) for more information.

Comment: I see! I made a note within my notes that I would stick to this style and completely forgot. I felt this way was easier than using (" " +variable name) and forgot to use it lol. Thank you!